# Forced PostgreSQL type convertion using JOOQ tool

Tags: postgresql, type-conversion, jooq

Is there a way to configure JOOQ tool to convert **smallint** to **Boolean** using 'forcedTypes' tag for PostgresSQL database, without providing org.jooq.Converter implementation?

This is how the current configuration looks like:

```
<forcedTypes>
    <forcedType>
        <name>BOOLEAN</name>
        <types>smallint.*</types>
    </forcedType>
<forcedTypes>
```

JOOQ v3.9.1 is being used. 
PostgreSQL v9.6.6.

And unfortunately receives the next exception while storing information into the database:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "is_complete" is of type smallint but expression is of type boolean
```

Also tried with MySQL database and similar convertion from tinyint to Boolean works fine without any errors:

```
<forcedTypes>
    <forcedType>
        <name>BOOLEAN</name>
        <types>tinyint.*</types>
    </forcedType>
</forcedTypes>
```

Comment: It works in MySQL because MySQL does not actually have a boolean data type. `boolean` is just an alias for `tinyint` there

Comment: Ok, so what the issue can be with PostgresSQL as I'm using smallint instead of pure boolean type? The way how it looks with smallint and tinyint is pretty similar

Comment: If you want a boolean, then why don't you use a `boolean`

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately need to use an existing database where booleans are stored as smallints :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this doesn't work as you're expecting (and it shouldn't). In jOOQ, the `BOOLEAN` data type is bound to JDBC as the native `BOOLEAN` type if the database supports it, e.g. PostgreSQL.

If the database doesn't support the type (e.g. MySQL / Oracle), then jOOQ will bind `0`/`1`/`NULL` number values. But you cannot enforce this behaviour for a dialect that would otherwise support `BOOLEAN` types. But then again, why not just write that converter? It's really simple. Just add:

```xml
<forcedTypes>
    <forcedType>
        <userType>java.lang.Boolean</userType>
        <converter>com.example.BooleanAsSmallintConverter</converter>
        <!-- A bit risky. Are all smallints really booleans in your database? -->
        <types>smallint.*</types>
    </forcedType>
<forcedTypes>
```

And then:

```java
class BooleanAsSmallintConverter extends AbstractConverter<Short, Boolean> {
    public BooleanAsSmallintConverter() {
        super(Short.class, Boolean.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean from(Short t) {
        return t == null ? null : t.shortValue() != (short) 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Short to(Boolean u) {
        return u == null ? null : u ? Short.valueOf((short) 1) : Short.valueOf((short) 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do that, but I doubt that this is what you had in mind. You will have to create [custom cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createcast.html) in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION bool2int2(IN bool, OUT int2)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
SELECT CASE WHEN $1 THEN 1::int2 WHEN $1 IS NOT NULL THEN 0::int2 END
$$;

DROP CAST IF EXISTS (bool AS int2);
CREATE CAST (bool AS int2)
WITH FUNCTION bool2int2(bool)
AS ASSIGNMENT;
```

Then this will work:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS booltest;
CREATE TABLE booltest (id serial, boolval int2);
INSERT INTO booltest (boolval) VALUES(true),(false),(null::bool);
SELECT * FROM booltest;
 id | boolval
----+---------
  1 |       1
  2 |       0
  3 | (null);
```